# Comparing Two Objects and Storing the Result

Tags: java, vector, nested, comparison

I have two objects and compare their Strings using an algorithm. I need to store the result, the two objects and the best values. Any suggestions?

```
void getDistances(Class m1, Class m2) {        

    Vector[] vector1 = new Vector[m1.getSize()]; // Object from my class
    Vector[] vector2 = new Vector[m2.getSize()]; // Object from my class

    for (int i = 0; i < vector1.length; i++) {
        Class current;
        Class next;

        current = m1.getInfo(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < vector2.length; j++) {
            prox = m2.getInfo(j);
            calcDist = lev.distance(current.getLabel(), next.getLabel());
            System.out.println(current + " <-> " + next + " = " + df.format(calcDist));

            if(something here){
                 // I think it's here the logic ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea will help me. Thanks.

Comment: What suggestions? What is the problem?

Comment: How to compare the results and store them? I need the best results and put them in some structure like HashMap(<results>, <m1>). There is a way to manipulate this data in this structure?

Comment: What is `calcDist`? `lev`? `df`? `prox`? What do you mean by "compare"?

Comment: calcDist is a double variable that receives a value, lev a algorithm that receives two Strings and returns a double value between them, df is just used to format decimal values, compare is value from i[0] -> j[0] = 0.6 and i[0] -> j[1] = 0.7 (I need compare here and store 0.7). prox is next***